# Generic array creation of inner class

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

The line where I create the array gives me a `Generic array creation` warning.
What is a good way to deal with this?

```
public class Foo<T> {

    void someMethod() {
        Point[] points = new Point[3];
    }

    class Point {
        float x, y;
    }
}
```

Comment: `static class Point {...`.  It looks like your inner class is just there to hold an `x` and `y`, and doesn't really need a hidden pointer to an instance of a `Foo<T>`.  If I'm right, then it should be a nested class and not an inner class.

Comment: @ajb That should be an answer (because it's the answer).

Comment: What is interesting is why `Point p = new Point()` compiles fine, while `Point[] points = new Points[3]` doesn't.

Comment: @Pshemo Even `List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>()` compiles fine, the restriction applies only to arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, let's figure out the reason why Java thinks that `new Point[3]` creates a generic array, while `Point` appears to be a non-generic class. This happens because `Point` is a non-static class, meaning that it has a hidden reference to `Foo<T>` embedded by the compiler. The class looks like this to Java:

```
class Foo$Point<T> {
    Foo<T> _hidden_Foo;
    float x, y;
}
```

The `Foo$`, `<T>` and `_hidden_Foo` are not there in the text of your program, but the compiler thinks that they are, because `Point` is an inner class of a generic class `Foo<T>`.

There are two ways of fixing this problem:

- You could make `static` your class `Point`, assuming that this is what you intended to do. See ajb's answer. However, any instance methods of `Point` would no longer be able to access `Foo<T>`'s members
- If `static` is not an option, replace the array with a `List<Point>` or another collection suitable to your needs. The restriction applies only to generic arrays, but generic collections are fine.

Here is how you can use a collection:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    void someMethod() {
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        ... // add three points to the list
    }
    class Point {
        float x, y;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about `Foo$Point<T>`. If I am not mistaken it would declare `T` in `Point` which would be different than one from `Foo<T>`. Do you have any source which could confirm it?

Comment: @Pshemo I think the `T` in `Foo$Point<T>` would be independent of `T` in `Foo<T>`. I put `<T>` for an illustration of why `Point` becomes generic, pretending that it's a top-level class. I did not intend to imply that Java compiler would generate code exactly like this, only that (1) there would be a reference to `Foo<T>` of the outer context, and (2) that's why the `Point` class would be considered generic.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to me that your `Point` class is just there to hold an `x` and a `y`, and there's no reason for it to have a hidden reference to an instance of a `Foo<T>`.  If this is correct, then `Point` should be a nested class, instead of an inner class.  Add the `static` keyword:

```
public class Foo<T> {

    void someMethod() {
        Point[] points = new Point[3];
    }

    static class Point {
        float x, y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Inner classes also have access to generic type of its outer class. Lets say that we have

```
class Foo<T> {

    class Point {
        float x, y;
        T value;
        T getValue(){
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

When you create instance of `Foo` like

```
Foo<String> f = new Foo<>();
```

we can create instance of its inner class based on its outer instance like

```
Point p = f.new Point();
// or 
//Foo<String>.Point p = f.new Point 
// if we are creating it for instance outside of Foo class
```

and compiler will know that `p.getValue()` returns String, so it can lets us use `p.getValue().charAt(0)`.

Now problem is that [generic type can't be used in any part of array type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html), which means that we can't use:

- `T[size]`.
- `Foo<T>[size]`
- or not even **`Foo<T>.Point[size]`**

The last example seems to be your case because

```
Point[] points = new Point[3];
```

is equivalent of

```
Point[] points = new Foo<T>.Point[3];
//  Foo<T> is type of outer instance on which you are invoking new
```

---

You have few options to solve this problem.

1. You can explicitly say that you don't want to use generic type by writing

   ```
   Point[] points = new Foo.Point[3];// we got rid of <T>
   ```

   but don't do that because [raw types are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).
2. Better solution is to avoid arrays and use Collection which support generics like `List<Point>`.

   ```
   List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
3. But probably best solution is to simply get rid of dependency of `T` from outer class `Foo`. This can be achieved by making your inner class static, which means it will not require instance of its outer class, so it will not need to know about which generic type is used by it.
   So you can simply use

   ```
   static class Point {
       float x, y;
   }
   ```

   and now

   ```
   Point[] points = new Point[3];
   ```

   will compile fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Point` is a non-static inner class. So `Point` written by itself means `Foo<T>.Point`, a parameterized type. You can't do `new Point[3]` (which is the same as `new Foo<T>.Point[3]`), for the same reason you can't do `new ArrayList<T>[3]`.

So let's take the analogy and ask, what do you do when you want to do

```
ArrayList<T>[] lists = new ArrayList<T>[3];
```

There are two ways:

1. Create an array of the raw type:

   `ArrayList<T>[] lists = new ArrayList[3];`
2. Or, if you don't like raw types, create an array of the wildcard-parameterized type:

   `ArrayList<T>[] lists = (ArrayList<T>[])new ArrayList<?>[3];`

So in our case, we have the same two solutions:

1. Create an array of the raw type. However, what's the raw type? It's not `Point`, as we've found; because that's implicitly parameterized. Instead, we need to explicitly qualify the name with the outer class names: `Foo.Point`:

   `Point[] points = new Foo.Point[3];`
2. Or, if you don't like raw types, create an array of the wildcard-parameterized type:

   `Point[] lists = (Point[])new Foo<?>.Point[3];`